# strtok and strcpy error

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy

I used `strtok` to split a string.

**[UPDATE]** I used your comments and answer for the new version below, but didn't work atm

```
int Crawl :: splitUrl(char ***tmp, int max_length, char *url)
{
 int idx=0;
 char * p;
 int i;

 p = strtok (url,"/");
 while (p != NULL && idx < max_length)
  {

   for (i=0;i<maxUrlSize-1 && p[i] != '\0';i++)
    (*tmp)[idx][i] = p[i];
   for ( ; i< maxUrlSize-1;i++)
    (*tmp)[idx][i] = '\0';

   printf("tmp[idx[%d]] %s\n",idx,(*tmp)[idx]);

   idx++;
   p = strtok (NULL, "/");
  }

 return idx;
};
```

The `printf("tmp[idx] ...` is correctly printed.

But in my main after I run the method:

```
  split_url = new char * [ maxUrlSplits ];
  for (int k=0;k<maxUrlSplits;k++)
   split_url[k] = new char [maxUrlSize];

  arr_size = crawl->splitUrl(&split_url,maxUrlSplits,url);
```

the array `split_url` is empty.

Compiler and gdb are fine.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: how do you know the array is empty? I can run it without any problem. The array split_url is not empty.

Comment: A bit OT but this is obviously C++, so why use arrays in the first place?

Comment: Please don't put status updates like [UPDATE] or [SOLVED] in your question titles - a clear summary of the question is all that's needed. Don't worry, everyone can see when you've updated your question.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you are not changing where the pointer is pointing, you only need to pass in a char * to your function. So

```
int Crawl :: splitUrl(char *tmp, int max_length, char *url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<maxUrlSize || p[i] != '\0';i++)
    tmp[idx][i] = p[i];
```

This for loop can't be correct. You copy bytes a long as **either** condition is true. I believe you should copy only when **both** are true.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is correct.
Every Parameter in C works as call by value, if you need a modification (fill your array), you should use a pointer.

```
       int Crawl :: splitUrl(char ***tmp, int max_length, char *url)
        {
         int idx=0;
         char * p;
         int i;

         p = strtok (url,"/");
         while (p != NULL)
          {

           for (i=0;i<maxUrlSize || p[i] != '\0';i++)
            (*tmp)[idx][i] = p[i];
           for ( ; i< maxUrlSize-1;i++)
            (*tmp)[idx][i] = '\0';

           printf("tmp[idx] %s\n",(*tmp)[idx]);

           idx++;
           p = strtok (NULL, "/");
          }


         return idx;
        };

...
      arr_size = crawl->splitUrl(&split_url,maxUrlSplits,url);
```

Comment: dereferencing pointers like that is strictly ANSI C compliant, works ever but not for NULL like in example